# monit: add NOALERT in an IF construct

Tags: monitoring, haproxy, monit, debian-jessie

On debian jessie, I have configured monit to check for `HAproxy` particular port forwardings, and to restart it if failed like this:

```
check process haproxy with pidfile /run/haproxy.pid
   group www-data
   start program = "/bin/systemctl start haproxy.service"
   stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop haproxy.service"
   if failed port 8080 protocol http request "/checker" then restart
   if failed port 8081 protocol http request "/checker" then restart
   if failed port 8082 protocol http request "/checker" then restart
   if 8 restarts within 8 cycles then unmonitor
```

I know it is possible to setup `noalert email` in a particular `check` environment. I wonder if if it is possible to do the same for particular `if` within the same `check`. In this particular case I would like monit to alert me only if the check on `port 8082` has failed, but not for the other 2.

I have tried to add something like this:

```
check process haproxy with pidfile /run/haproxy.pid
   group www-data
   start program = "/bin/systemctl start haproxy.service"
   stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop haproxy.service"
   if 8 restarts within 8 cycles then unmonitor

check host site-a with address localhost
  noalert email@address
  depends haproxy
  if failed port 8080 protocol http request "/checker" then exec "/usr/bin/monit restart haproxy"

check host site-b with address localhost
  noalert email@address
  depends haproxy
  if failed port 8081 protocol http request "/checker" then exec "/usr/bin/monit restart haproxy"

check host site-c with address localhost
  depends haproxy
  if failed port 8082 protocol http request "/checker" then exec "/usr/bin/monit restart haproxy"
```

This configuration works, but I need to `exec monit`like an external program, and I wonder if there is a way to do it directly in an `if construct`within the same `check`. If I use the following, `monit` will start without complaining, but it does not consider the `noalert` instruct:

```
check process haproxy with pidfile /run/haproxy.pid
   group www-data
   start program = "/bin/systemctl start haproxy.service"
   stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop haproxy.service"
   if failed port 8080 protocol http request "/checker" then
     restart
     noalert email@address
   if failed port 8081 protocol http request "/checker" then
     restart
     noalert email@address
   if failed port 8082 protocol http request "/checker" then restart
   if 8 restarts within 8 cycles then unmonitor
```

Any idea?

Best regards